# Mysql - Load Data Infile formatting a date

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Edited:
I can store the records of a file with only one line with this format.

```
0,2016-03-31-13:48:16.435,0.705486,1,F2221-222
```

But when I try to store a file with 2 or more lines i get an error.

```
0,2016-03-31-13:48:16.435,0.705486,1,F2221-222
1,2016-03-31-13:48:16.435,0.56606096,2,F2221-222
```

I am using:

```
load data infile 'flight3021' 
into table signal_times
fields terminated BY ','
(signaltime_id,@var1,value,signal_id,flight_number)
SET time = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i:%S.%f')
```

Error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cmsdbdev`.`signal_times`, CONSTRAINT `FK_r2e4qo5suuwrlkr08ryebv14i` FOREIGN KEY (`flight_number`) REFERENCES `flight_data` (`flight_number`))
```

The strange thing is that if I do normal insertion of this 2 lines it works, so its related with a FK constraint violation error. I think it has to be an issue with the load data infile.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your tables? Do you have triggers on your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'2016-03-31-13:16:24.861'` is loaded as "`'2016-03-31-13:16:24.861'`", which is why it is not a valid `datetime`.

I use a `TRIM` function to try to work around that.

For multiple lines, `lines terminated by` is needed.

```
load data infile '/home/jinggang.sjg/data1' 
into table signal_times
fields terminated BY ',' ESCAPED BY ""
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(signaltime_id,@var1,value,signal_id,flight_number)
SET time = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i:%S.%f');
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect! the time is load properly if I see it well. What do you mean about using TRIM? The time should be between quotation marks in the file? '2016-03-31-13:16:24.861'. I don't let any space.

Comment: The normal datetime is '2016-03-31-13:16:24.861', but here it will be loaded as "'2016-03-31-13:16:24.861'".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

File: `'/path/to/file/flight3021'`

```bsh
0,2016-03-31-13:48:16.435,0.705486,1,F2221-222
1,2016-03-31-13:48:16.435,0.56606096,2,F2221-222
```

MySQL command-line:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.11    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `signal_times`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `signal_times` (
    ->   `signaltime_id` INT UNSIGNED,
    ->   `time` TIMESTAMP(3),
    ->   `value` DECIMAL(10,8),
    ->   `signal_id` INT UNSIGNED,
    ->   `flight_number` VARCHAR(10)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/flight3021'
    ->   INTO TABLE `signal_times`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    ->   (`signaltime_id`,
    ->    @`var1`,
    ->    `value`,
    ->    `signal_id`,
    ->    `flight_number`
    ->   )
    ->   SET `time` = STR_TO_DATE(@`var1`,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i:%S.%f');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `signaltime_id`,
    ->   `time`,
    ->   `value`,
    ->   `signal_id`,
    ->   `flight_number`
    -> FROM
    ->   `signal_times`;
+---------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| signaltime_id | time                    | value      | signal_id | flight_number |
+---------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
|             0 | 2016-03-31 13:48:16.435 | 0.70548600 |         1 | F2221-222     |
|             1 | 2016-03-31 13:48:16.435 | 0.56606096 |         2 | F2221-222     |
+---------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```